# How do I search by superadmins within a get_users query?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

On a WordPress multisite installation, I am trying to get the IDs of all superadmins for my site using a function in my theme. (new to multisite here). However, I don't seem to be able to access them with a get_users() function as below:

```
$roles     = [ 'superadministrator','administrator'];

$user_ids = get_users( array( 'role__in' => $roles, 'fields' => 'ID' ) );
```

There is the get_super_admins() function, but that just seems to return a list of names, not IDs. Also, I would like to just be able to run one query instead of two, so this function isn't ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Super Admin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#super-admin) is a special role and unlike the other roles like Administrator and Subscriber, the Super Admin role doesn't get saved to the same WordPress option as the other roles. Instead, the option name is `site_admins` and it only stores the *username* of users who were granted the Super Admin role. So `superadministrator` is not a default role in WordPress, i.e. no such role.

But then, since [`get_super_admins()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_super_admins/) returns the usernames saved in the `site_admins` option, then you can use that with [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) by setting the `login__in` arg to those usernames like so:

```php
$user_ids = get_users( array( 'login__in' => get_super_admins(), 'fields' => 'ID' ) );
```

Or maybe like so, to include all Administrator users:

```php
$admins = get_users( array(
    'role__in' => 'administrator',
    'fields'   => array( 'user_login' ),
) );

$logins = array_merge( get_super_admins(), wp_list_pluck( $admins, 'user_login' ) );

$user_ids = get_users( array(
    'login__in' => $logins,
    'fields'    => 'ID',
) );
```

But yes, the above requires two `get_users()` calls.

*[**Edit**]* Note that the `blog_id` [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/) defaults to the current site ID, so if you want to retrieve the super admins in all sites (or the entire network), then you can set the `blog_id` to `0` like so:

```php
$user_ids = get_users( array(
    'login__in' => get_super_admins(),
    'fields'    => 'ID',
    'blog_id'   => 0, // set it to 0 to search in all sites
) );
```

However, that could result in performance issues if you have a large network (many sites, users, etc.), so you may need to find an alternative, or a different code for retrieving all the super admins.

Comment: Hmm, I thought this would work, but it's actually having issues.  get_super_admins() returns all the superadmins for my network, but the get_users query only returns my superadmins that are assigned to this site.  So I'm still getting unassigned superadmins in my results.

Any ideas?

Comment: OK, got it now, I used the first code snippet you submitted, but added 'blog_id' => 0 which searches the whole network as described at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278367/how-to-search-users-globally-on-a-multisite-install.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't come across in my mind that you're referring to all sites in the whole network. Anyway, I've added an update to the answer.